# How do I set the position of a dialog so it is centered in it's parent frame?

Tags: java, swing, positioning, jdialog

I have a dialog class with a constructor like the following

```
public SampleDialog(JComponent parent, String title){
    super((Frame)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(Frame.class, parent), title, false);
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
    init();
  }
```

However, this positions the dialog so that it's upper right hand corner is in the center of it's parent.  I would like the dialog's center on top of the parent component's center.  How do I do this?  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to move setLocationRelativeTo(parent) to the end of the constructor.  It needs to be called after pack() is called, which I was calling in my init method.

```
public SampleDialog(JComponent parent, String title){
    super((Frame)SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(Frame.class, parent), title, false);
    init();
    setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
  }

init(){
  // initialization code goes here
  pack();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar to this, but I used

```
Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
```

and then used .getScreenSize, but I am sure you could use it to get the width and height of your parent application with something like this:

```
myApplication.setLocation((int)dim.getWidth(),(int)dim.getHeight());
```

I hope this helps.